# Pydantic Error while working or pandas profiling

Tags: python, pydantic

how can i deal with this error

```
import pandas as pd
from ydata_profiling import ProfileReport


PydanticImportError: `BaseSettings` has been moved to the `pydantic-settings` package. See https://docs.pydantic.dev/2.4/migration/#basesettings-has-moved-to-pydantic-settings for more details.

For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.4/u/import-error
```

Answer (score 1):

You're likely looking at an older documentation or guide from before BaseSettings was moved. Install pydantic-settings then import.

Install:

```
pip install pydantic-settings
```

Import:

```
from pydantic_settings import BaseSettings
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the previous version of pydantic using the following command:

```
pip install "pydantic==1.*"
```

But there will be a conflict with ydata-profiling when you are downgrading the pydantic, first downgrade the ydata-profiling.

```
pip install ydata-profiling==4.0.0
```